# Commutativity of Position Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

Does the position operator $q_{i}$ of one harmonic oscillator commute with the position operator $q_{j}$ of another different harmonic oscillator? In other words, is $q_{i} q_{j} = q_{j} q_{i}$ true? Note $i \neq j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to ask is whether the position operators of a system with two harmonic oscillators , labeled as $A$ and $B$, commute. If the system is not entangled, so operator $\hat{q_a}$ act only on $A$, $\hat{q_b}$ act on $B$ individually. Assume that the state of the system is $\psi$ , $\psi=\psi_a\psi_b$. So $\hat{q_a}\hat{q_b}\psi=\hat{q_a}\hat{q_b}\psi_a\psi_b=\hat{q_a}\psi_a\hat{q_b}\psi_b=q_b\psi_bq_a\psi_a=q_bq_a\psi_b\psi_a=\hat{q_b}\hat{q_a}\psi_b\psi_a$. In other words, they commute.

Comment: What if the system is entangled?

Comment: @nchar： If it is entangled, you need to introduce density matrix, and then you can't deduce like that genrally, I think.